# Imputation of qualitative variables

Tags: data-imputation

I am working on a data set were few qualitative features are having missing values.

Qualitative columns having null values(nan):

```
uniques in  Gender ['Male' 'Female' nan]
uniques in  Married ['No' 'Yes' nan]
uniques in  Dependents ['0' '1' '2' '3+' nan]
uniques in  Self_Employed ['No' 'Yes' nan]
uniques in  Credit_History [  1.   0.  nan]
```

I used *mode* for imputation.
Requesting experts: please share some best practices for imputation or resources with practical examples(less theory).

I am using pandas for analysis
(PS- i am new to data science)

Comment: You probably need to find introductory material on multiple imputation. Imputing the same value (the mode) for every instance of a missing value is not ideal.

Comment: @ mdewey thanks for your response, can you share some resources with more practical approach.

Comment: https://missingdata.lshtm.ac.uk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is much to imputation in the field of statistics, ranging from full likelihood/Bayesian models to multiple imputation and to crude approximations that are faster such as single imputation.  Full modeling or multiple imputation are necessary to get the right uncertainty (e.g. standard errors, confidence limits, credible intervals).  There's a lot to study.  My chapter on imputation in *Regression Modeling Strategies* is a start.  Free course notes for RMS are [here](http://fharrell.com/links).  If using multiple imputation I'd recommend predictive mean matching for your case.

Comment: @ frank thanks for help. I am thinking about an approach, correct me if i am wrong. If i want to impute for column x,I will take the complete train data having no missing value and create a model were response variable will be x and try to predict the missing value.Is it a correct approach or i am making a conceptual mistake?

Comment: My RMS notes go into detail about what does not work correctly with that approach.  Note that multiple imputation in the context of model validation is not well worked out yet.